What's the best way to solidify a model with complex/messy/disorganized geometry? (Mix of 3D print/Blender problem)
I have a model of a Porsche Boxter that has several layers that "don't exist" (basically it has a bunch of holes in it). I want to make it 3D printable/3D printer-ready, but every time I solidify the model with the solidify modifier it messes up the entire file and becomes really bumpy. I can't separate the parts easily because the geometry is insane. I also tried remeshing but it kept crashing my computer and ruining the definition/sharpness of the shape of the model. I've made it manifold as well and it still doesn't work when I run it through the 3D printer slicer. Any suggestions?
